# swfobject embed youtube elastic videos height issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, flash

Im having trouble making my embedded videos from youtube elastic.  I tried more or less everything i could think of, and im running out of ideas.

As the code shows below i have 2 html block tags with 2 different id´s which i put the video int he last, the placeholder.  I tried the width and height tricks suggested by: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos

But none so far have worked.

It will get elastic in the width, but the height dosent follow.  So in terms its elastic but only in the width :I

Anyone knows a solution, what did i miss? :)

```
        //create video area
        var $videoDisplay = $('<section id="video-display"></div>');
        var $videoPlaceholder = $('<div id="video-placeholder"></div>');

        $videoDisplay.insertAfter('#title-search-container');
        $videoDisplay.append($videoPlaceholder);

        $("#area").html($videoDisplay);


        //embed player
        swfobject.embedSWF('http://www.youtube.com/e/' + id + '?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer', 
        'video-placeholder', '100%', '100%', '9.0.0', null, null, { allowScriptAccess: "always" }, 
        { id: "myyoutubeplayer" } );
```

Comment: Please use this site (http://jsfiddle.net/) to reproduce your issue

Comment: never used it before, how does it take to set a site up there ?

Comment: Just took a good look at it.  I dont see how i can use this, i got many external files.  I could upload it to a domain instead, would that help ?

Comment: Sure - something is better than nothing I guess

Comment: ok give me 1 moment please :)

Comment: http://test.nem-chaos.com/    here it is.  For some reason it dosent work in my firefox, so i used chrome to test this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
#video-display {
   height: 100%;
}
```

instead auto;

Comment: It seems that it can scale a lot more now, however im running into a new problem now.  But the video scales, and thats what i asked for.  Thanks :)